# Automatically generate a weekly overview of google calendar via mail?

Tags: google-calendar, email, notifications

I want to set up a Google Calendar where appointments that are relevant for a group of people will be annotated.

However, not all of them will be using google calendar. Thus, I wanted to generate a weekly overview mail that is sent to all relevant email adresses (not necessarily @gmail ones).
This mail would ideally include all appointments of the next week and their description, date, place etc.

I googled this, but I could only find third party programs where I would have to sign up for a free trial or something. I would like to do this without signing up for another service.

Comment: Show what you have tried. Among the things that you might try is to use Google Apps Script -> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

Answer (score 0):

You can use n8n (node.js addon) on free heroku account to get your events from Google Calendar and sent mail using i.e. python.